# JDialog in new thread doesn't respond

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdialog

I want to create a JDialog in another thread (will show time),
while in the main thread, a function will run..

when I create the dialog, it is shown, but it is "stuck"...and I can't see
its components...

Only when the function in the main thread finish - The dialog is shown correctly..

How can I fix it?

Comment: please add some code on how you create it.

Comment: We need more code, but I guess you are not aware that everything related to Swing should run in the event dispatching thread (Swing EDT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a large task on the Swing EDT then it will block UI elements from being repainted, since that's the thread that all Swing painting happens on.

The only sensible way around this is to run your large task on a separate thread. Look into the `SwingWorker` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Answer (score 1):

Call the JDialog creation inside SwingUtilities.invokeLater or invokeAndWait

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the awt event queue to open it.  Just putting it on a separate thread does not work to my knowledge

must start the Face editor on another thread for the JFrame menus and accelerators to work,

```
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            editFace();
        }
    });
```

where editFace() contains the code to start and show the new frame

```
            Viewer2D v = new Viewer2D(this);
            this.addFaceEditor(FaceToEdit, v);
            v.DrawFace(FaceToEdit);
            v.showAndRaise();
```